Does SuiteQL support Update Statement?
Does Suiteql support update query statement in rest api body? currently I am fetching netsuite data using rest api with suiteql but I am curious to know about update/insert/delete statement query. if not what is other approach?
sample sql query - select * from Transaction


Take a look at the following NetSuite help tutorials.  You can update by using the PATCH HTTP method.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545142173.html

In the following example, the name of a specific customer record
instance is updated. In REST web services, you can perform such an
update using the PATCH HTTP method. The PATCH method expects a request
body with the same fields that can be retrieved using the GET method.
In this example, the name (entityid) of the record instance 107
retrieved in the previous example is changed from "Alan Rath" to
"Updated Customer". Send the following request to perform the update.

PATCH https://demo123.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/107
BODY { "entityid": "Updated Customer" } 

    

You can also use the Upsert method

The upsert operation enables you to either create a record,or update an existing record. You can only use the upsert operation when you use an external ID in the request URL and when you use the PUT HTTP method.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_156335203191.html
PUT http://demo123.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/eid:CID002
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith"
} 

    

To delete take a look at the following link:

To delete a record instance, you need to specify the record type and the instance identifier. The following is a delete request.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545142287.html
DELETE https://demo123.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/107 

    

